# How to add a linefeed in VBA macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am new to VBA macro and need advice on the following code.

[Excel cells]

```vb
Sub Create_email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim strName As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strBody As String

strName = Range("B1").Value
strTo = Range("B2").Value
strCc = Range("B3").Value

If strName <> "" Then
    e_msg = "Hello " & strName & vbCrLf & _
    "Welcome Back " & vbCrLf & _
    "Regards " & vbCrLf & _
    "Management "
    MsgBox (e_msg)
End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    ' Create Email subject
    strSubj = "Hello " & strName
    
    ' Create body of email
    *strBody = "<html> <body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Arial>" & e_msg & "<br><br>" & _
    "Please let us know if there are any issues. <br><br>" & _
    "</body> </html>"*

    With OutMail
        .To = strTo
        .CC = strCc
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = strSubj
        .htmlBody = strBody
        .Display  '.Send 'or use .Display
    End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I was hoping to create the email in this format

```
Hello John

Welcome Back Regards Management

Please let us know if there are any issues.
```

but the code does not add the new line between John and Welcome in the email body

```
Hello John Welcome Back Regards Management 
Please let us know if there are any issues.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `vbCrLf` in your string isn't showing up as line breaks in your HTML body. There are some options:

1. Replace them in your `e_msg` with `<br><br>`

   `e_msg = "Hello " & strName & "<br><br>Welcome Back<br><br>Regards<br><br>Management"`
2. Replace them in `e_msg` afer the fact:

   `e_msg = Replace(e_msg, vbCrLf, "<br><br>")`

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful.